# Как сделать модальное окно на Angular 2

Tags: angular2, popup

Не пойму логики создания модального окна в Angular 2. Как сделать корневой компонент модального окна, что бы из любого другого компонента можно было его вызвать и передать любой компонент? Плагины не надо предлогать.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZAZqZu?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Можно в корневом компоненте сделать верстку прописать ngIf и через сервис запускать в нужные моменты... Не знаю на сколько это правильно)) Или вообще сделать компонент который будет отрисовываться если условие соблюдается!

Comment: Пошел по подобному пути. Нашел [статью](https://habrahabr.ru/post/305892/) на хабре. Связь через сервис крайне странно выглядит, но работает